# (Newbie) Why won't this variable decrement?

Tags: javascript

I've been stuck on this for a second now, does anyone know why currentCount won't decrement by 20 if htmlButtonToBuy is pressed when currentCount is >= 20?

Tried my best to take scope into account, but I'm officially clueless.

```
const $id = document.getElementById.bind(document);
      // i know, i know. forgive me for the sin above. i should learn jQuery.
var currentCount = 0;

$id('htmlButtonForIncrementing').addEventListener("click", function(){
    currentCount++;
    $id('counter').innerHTML = currentCount;
});   // works!

$id('htmlButtonToBuy').addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (currentCount < 20){
      // irrelevant
    } if (currentCount >= 20) {
        currentCount - 20;   // doesn't work 
        $id('counter').innerHTML = currentCount;
    }
});
```

It's for a stupid clicker game I´m trying to make for myself. :)

Thanks!

Comment: `currentCount - 20;` is a useless expression-statement, you need to assign the value to some variable, e.g. `currentCount = currentCount - 20;`, or the shorthand `currentCount -= 20;`. PS: I assume you don't really mean "stuck on this for a second" literally, as you are expected to try yourself for more than a second ;)

Comment: Googling "js subtract number from variable" gives this as first result: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-math-in-javascript-with-operators

Comment: Thanks for having an answer so soon! Didn't know -= was a thing. Have a good one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting into your if condition to decrease the number just fine, but you aren't subtracting from your variable properly.  You can do this 1 of 2 ways:

Option 1:

```
currentCount = currentCount - 20;
```

Option 2:

```
currentCount -= 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

try **currentCount -= 20;**
because currentCount - 20 does not assign anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a variable assignment.
Your line

```
currentCount - 20;
```

should be

```
currentCount -= 20; // which is equal to currentCount = currentCount - 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentCount - 20` isn't a subtraction assignment, missing the latter.

Correct:
`currentCount -= 20` (shorter) or `currentCount = currentCount - 20`

Also, you can use `else` in the conditional.

```
$id('htmlButtonToBuy').addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (currentCount < 20){
      // irrelevant
    } else {
        currentCount -= 20;
        $id('counter').innerHTML = currentCount;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JavaScript, but it is the same concept as other languages.

Basically;

```js
currentCount - 20;
```

Does not do anything. Actually, it does, but it doesn't do anything meaningful. The computer just calculates what `currentCount - 20` is, but you don't tell it
to store the result so it doesn't. The result is lost. So to store the decremented value back in the variable you have to re-assign it to the result;

```js
currentCount = currentCount - 20;
```

Now this is pretty long, but luckily most languages (including JavaScript) implement a way to shorten this;

```js
currentCount -= 20;
```